# CSS problem with dropdown appearing back of the text

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, frontend

[image: DROPDOWN IMAGE]

My dropdown is showing back of the text. I want my dropdown to show over the text in green background. I tried z-indexing but failed. Thanks in advance

Comment: set dropdown to ```position:relative``` and make sure when you ask question please provide code snippate as well

Comment: See httpos://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with providing code in your question so we can help find the problem.